# Can I require_once a parent before session_start() to be able to include a child object in $_SESSION?

Tags: php, oop, session, inheritance

In PHP, I must `require_once()` the classes of the objects I want to put in session before `session_start()`.

If I want to put in session an instance of a class which is a child of a parent class, can I just `require_once()` the parent class, or do I need to list all the children classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (assuming that you have individual files with each class), you will need to `require_once` the file/class for the parent and the child class (otherwise the child class won't know it's parent class). `session_start` should really have nothing to do with it.

Comment: I had been told that the objects in session had to be `require_once()` before creation of the session.  If that's not the case, then it simplifies everything.

Comment: Actually, I have found out that if I don't `require_once` the file for the class I put in session, the object is then shown in the session as `_PHP_Incomplete_Class`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to require the `child` classes & `parent` classes both. Because

- It is of child class, of whose you are trying to add an instance
- The object is the child, will eventually use method from the classes, which might go up to parent classes also

SO, bottom line. Yes, You do need to require all the classes.